# Ext JS 5 clustered chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Did somebody tried to implement clustered chart in Ext JS 5?

I see the example in Ext JS [Legasy Kitchen Sink](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/charts-kitchensink/#clustered-bar) .

But there are no example in [usual kitchen sink](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#bar-charts).

I tried to copy example from legacy kitchen sink but cannot make it work on my local server. All I can get is displayed on attached screenshot :

[image]

May be the problem is in Ext JS version? I use 5.0.0.970 and it seems that it is the latest version for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
It seems that in current version "sencha-charts" does not have clustered chart functionality. If you need it you may use "ext-charts". Add it to "requires" section of your app.json. Then the example from http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/charts-kitchensink/#clustered-bar will work.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by using `stacked: false`.

Code examples.

Chart:

```
Ext.define('App.Domain.Chart', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.CartesianChart',
    title: 'Chart',
    alias: 'widget.appDomainChart',
    legend: {
        docked: 'bottom'
    },
    interactions: ['itemhighlight'],
    colors: ['blue', 'red'],
    axes: [{
        type: 'numeric',
        position: 'left',
        adjustByMajorUnit: true,
        grid: true,
        fields: ['ActualParameter'],
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'category',
        position: 'bottom',
        grid: true,
        fields: ['ControlValue'],
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'left',
        title: ['Fact', 'Planned'],
        xField: 'ControlValue',
        yField: ['ActualParameter', 'PlannedParameter'],
        display: 'outside',
        stacked: false,
        style: {
            opacity: 0.80
        },
        highlight: {
            fillStyle: 'green'
        },
        tooltip: {
            style: 'background: #fff',
            renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
                var browser = item.series.getTitle()[Ext.Array.indexOf(item.series.getYField(), item.field)];
                this.setHtml(browser + ': ' + storeItem.get(item.field) + '.');
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "Id": 54,
        "ObjectName": null,
        "StageName": null,
        "Result": "Result 1",
        "ControlValue": "Control value 1",
        "PlannedParameter": 10.0,
        "ActualParameter": 10.0,
        "Unit": "days",
        "Indicator": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 55,
        "ObjectName": null,
        "StageName": null,
        "Result": "",
        "ControlValue": "Control value 2",
        "PlannedParameter": 3.0,
        "ActualParameter": 3.0,
        "Unit": "departments",
        "Indicator": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 56,
        "ObjectName": null,
        "StageName": null,
        "Result": "",
        "ControlValue": "Control value 3",
        "PlannedParameter": 100.0,
        "ActualParameter": 100.0,
        "Unit": "%",
        "Indicator": 4
      }
    ],
    "totalCount": 3
  },
  "errors": [],
  "success": true,
  "totalCount": 3,
  "globalErrors": []
}
```

Result as image: http://screencast.com/t/ilb0mYZIUJ4

Comment: You the man... Stacked property is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please change xtype: 'chart' to xtype: 'cartesian'

They removed chart component and added cartesian, polar and space filling components.

Ref: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.CartesianChart

Comment: Did you try to implement clustered chart using cartesian? Does not work for me.